# laravel 5 redirect user after login based on user's role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My 'users' table has a 'role' column and when users are registered or logged in, I want them to be redirected based on their role column. how can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I added this function to AuthController.php and everything fixed magically

```
public function authenticated($request , $user){
    if($user->role=='super_admin'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard') ;
    }elseif($user->role=='brand_manager'){
        return redirect()->route('brands.dashboard') ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning this method will not redirect users after registering. The `authenticated` function is only called in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the Authentication system provided with Laravel you can override the `redirectPath` method in your `Auth\AuthController`.

For example, this would redirect a user with role 'admin' to `/admin` and any other user to `/account`:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (\Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
        return "/admin";
        // or return route('routename');
    }

    return "/account";
    // or return route('routename');
}
```

You could also use [Laravel Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization) (introduced in 5.1.11) to manage role logic.

Comment: any redirect in the redirectPath() function will result in this error: ErrorException in Response.php line 337:
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Comment: You do not need to return a redirect, just a string of the path

Comment: I want to use named routes, I cant return any string

Comment: as shown (commented out) in my answer, you can use the `route()` function to return a named route. The `route()` function, just like `asset()` and `action()` returns the requested URL as a string.

Answer (score 7):

In laravel 5.7 there is no AuthController.php so you have to go **Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php** and add the below function,

If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a **redirectTo** method instead of a **redirectTo** property

```
protected function redirectTo()
{

    if($user->role=='super_admin'){
        return '/path1';
    }elseif($user->role=='brand_manager'){
        return '/path2';
    }   

}
```

Comment: $user isn't being passed into this function so that code won't work as presented. \Auth::user() works but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

You can do this handle the request in the Middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.php inside the handle function like this:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }else{
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: MIddleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.php is the guest middleware. So everything that is for guest,you can't go there if  you are logged in. After you login, everything is protected, every route related to user, except logout.
So, It will work if you are logged in and try to visit a page which is protected by guest middleware, redirection will work. But when you login first time, this will not work. 
Better way is to override `redirectTo()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I write this in case someone consider useful. If you want to redirect always and not only on Login, I did it on web.php like this:

```
  Route::get('/home', function () {
    switch(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->role){
        case 'admin':
            return redirect(route('home.admin'));
            break;
        case 'employee':
            return redirect(route('home.employee'));
            break;
        default:
            return '/login';
            break;
    }
});

Route::get('/home/admin', 'HomeController@indexAdmin')->name('home.admin');
Route::get('/home/employee', 'HomeController@indexEmployee')->name('home.employee');
```

So every time they click on /home is redirect to the url you want, you could do it too with '/'.

Answer (score 0):

for laravel 9 i implement the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers, HasRoles;
    
    public function redirectTo(){

        if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('Adm1','Adm2')){
            return $this->redirectTo = route('viewAdm') ;
            
        }elseif(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('Usuario')){
            return $this->redirectTo = route('home') ;
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```