# Laravel 5.2 Custom redirect after login based on role

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I use auth scaffold and I can change default redirect after login success in `AuthController.php` at this variable `protected $redirectTo = '/';`

But how I can redirect to custom url after successful login based on role like this

```
if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'customer'){
return redirect('/customer');
}else if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'partner'){
return redirect('/partner');
}else{
return redirect('/admin');
}
```

I don't know where should I put these logic.

This `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812134/laravel-5-redirect-user-after-login-based-on-users-role solution` doesn't work for me.

Comment: *"doesn't work for me"* - why?
What does your `users` table look like?

Comment: @AndyHolmes `users -> role_id, email, password, full_name, so on` and `roles -> id, name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to redirect the log-in user to a controller where this authentication process is!

AuthController.php

```
protected $redirectTo = '/Controller';
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/Controller', 'LogInController@overview');
```

LogInController

```
public funtion overview(){ 
if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'customer'){
return redirect('/customer');
}else if(Auth::user()->role->name == 'partner'){
return redirect('/partner');
}else{
return redirect('/admin');
}
}
```

Good luck!