# Laravel middleware login redirect

Tags: laravel, redirect

how to create middleware redirect about role. I have 2 middleware, first Admin, next User. Need redirect after login, if role Admin, example redirect to /admin, if User redirect to /user.

Admin middleware:

```
if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isRole() == "Admin"){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('login');
```

User middleware:

```
 if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isRole() == "User"){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('login');
```

WEB routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth' => 'admin']], function (){
    Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth' => 'user']], function (){
    Route::resource('/user', 'AdminController');
});
```

});

Comment: Instead of taking the user back to login (even when they could be logged in already), why not take them to their appropriate page?

Comment: I think if you want to redirect after login, a middleware it's not the class to do that, you can do it on your login controller. Ie: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812134/laravel-5-redirect-user-after-login-based-on-users-role

Answer (score 0):

You can make your admin/user middleware to inherit laravel's Authenticate middleware: `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`, then have their definitions as below.

Admin Middleware-

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    // Ensure auth - this will automagically re-direct if not authed.
    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
    if(Auth::user()->isRole() == "Admin")
        return $next($request);
    return redirect('/user-default-page')
}

// You can define this for your un-authenticated redirects
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    return '/login';
}
```

User middleware will then be:-

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    // Ensure auth - this will automagically re-direct if not authed.
    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
    if(Auth::user()->isRole() == "User")
        return $next($request);
    return redirect('/admin-default-page')
}

// You can define this for your un-authenticated redirects
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    return '/login';
}
```

For routes:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    // Put here admin routes, e.g
    Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController');
}
Route::group(['middleware' => 'user'], function () {
    // Put here user routes, e.g
    Route::resource('/users', 'UserController');
}

// You can still use the default auth routes, say for routes that (somehow), both admin and user can access
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('/dashboard', 'DashboardController');
}
```

Comment: Kindly share you code, one of your middleware classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Admin Middleware

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1)
      {
        return $next($request);
      }else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
      }

    }

// User Middleware

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2 )
      {
        return $next($request);
      }else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
      }

    }

// Admin Route Group
Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function (){
    Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

})
// User Middleware
Route::group(['as'=>'user.','prefix'=>'user','namespace'=>'Author','middleware'=>['auth','user']], function (){
    Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

});
```